# How do you code in a power specrtum in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program attempting to make a power spectrum of a set of data. In an attempt to test it I created a list of 1000 samples of twenty sine waves whose frequencies I knew in order to test it. This failed and didn't give the anticipated results. Here is the program which was supposed to compute the power spectrum through a dft with unsorted_v being the list of terms.

```
import cmath

N = len(unsorted_v)

for k in range(N):

     a = 0
     for n in range(N):
         a += unsorted_v[n] * cmath.exp(-2j * cmath.pi * k * n * (1/N))
     b = (abs(a)**2)*(1/N)
     print(k, ":", b)
```

Thank you for any help which you can give on what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: How did it fail? What results did it give? More information needed.

Comment: it was supposed to only give a non zero answer at the frequencies 8, 13, 14, 18, 23, 25, 32, 33, 38, 41, 48, 51, 64, 73, 79, 82, 85, 91, and 100 hz frequencies as generated by the sum of sin(#*2*pi/desired frequency). It gave me a non zero answer at all frequencies between 1 and 100, and at 125 and then tapered off towars zero for all other successive frequencies.